# Building Web Portfolio from groundup

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, startup, portfolio

I have been working with .NET for about 2 years now and I want to build a complete website out of everything I have learned so far. Essentially I would like the site to represent my portfolio.

Here are my skill set in short:
Core Language:
- .NET C#, ASP MVC3, Javascript, AngularJS, SASS

Tools
- Visual Studio 2013, AnkhSVN, CruiseControl

DB
- MS SQL, Postgres, ORACLE

I would like to know the list of things I would need to make this happen. I looked around and I find information in bits an pieces but can't seem to get the whole picture, starting from development of a workable cshtml page to its deployment to a webpage.

Here's what I know so far:
- I need a domain name
- I need a host
..................that's it..  :(

Comment: I think your question is too vague.  You might start trying to put the pieces together and ask specific questions as you go.

Comment: oh come on! If you have all those skills you wouldn't need to be asking such a simplistic question. It's also not an appropriate question for this site

Comment: I'm sorry for not asking the exact question but that is where my actual weakness lies at the moment. I know how to have a solution set and run in the local machine. What I don't know is how I deploy it such that the same will appear in a domain I reserved from a site say Godaddy

Comment: simple...ftp from your IDE to your domain

Comment: @charlietfl Did you mean dump all my code into website's root?

Comment: no...ftp client will transfer to same directory structure that you develop locally

Answer (score 0):

Since no one bothered to look at the big picture and were only focused on answering when provided a specific question, I talked with some experts on the topic and figured how I could get my site up and running.

Right now I'm running two test sites, one on Windows Azure and another on regular GoDaddy host.

Windows Azure provided 30 day trial period and publishing was REALLY EASY. Please note that I found pricing to be a little steep for a test project.

Steps:

1. Register at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/
2. Develop your test web project as usual.
3. Right Click and Publish Select Profile->"publish target" as "Windows Azure
   Websites" and follow instruction there on.
4. Click Publish

Things were a little lengthy for GoDaddy.
Steps:

1. Get domain name and hosting
2. Develop your test web project as usual.
3. Right Click and Publish Select Connection -> "Publish Marget" as FTP and fill in the FTP information as provided by the host.
4. Click Publish

For GoDaddy you might run into some config issue, so make sure you turn off customErrors so you can debug your issue

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

PS Regards to charlietfl for the FTP suggestion.